# Electron getApplicationMenu returning menu with MenuItems that shouldn't exist

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to make an electron menu and I've set it up like this:

```
const template = [{
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [{
            label: 'Save',
            click() {
                console.log('TODO save');
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Preferences',
            click() {
                console.log('TODO preferences');
            }
        }]
    }, {
        label: 'Edit',
        submenu: [{
            role: 'undo'
        }, {
            role: 'redo'
        }, {
            type: 'separator'
        },...]
    }, {
        label: 'View',
        submenu: [{
            role: 'reload'
        }, {
            role: 'forcereload'
        },...]
    }, {
        label: 'Insert',
        submenu: [{
            label: 'Testing',
            enabled: false,
            click() {
                win.webContents.send('insert-clicked');
            }
        }...]
    }
];

console.log(template);
menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
win.setMenu(menu);
console.log(Menu.getApplicationMenu()); //something with 'window' and 'help'
console.log(menu.getApplicationMenu()); //error
```

The first `console.log(template)` logs the template as expected. The menu is also shown as expected in the actual app. But when I `console.log(Menu.getApplicationMenu())` I get the following:

```
Menu {
  commandsMap:
   { '2':
      MenuItem {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [Object],
        type: 'submenu',
        role: null,
        accelerator: null,
        icon: null,
        sublabel: '',
        enabled: true,
        visible: true,
        checked: false,
        commandId: 2,
        click: [Function],
        menu: [Circular] },
     '12':
      MenuItem {
        label: 'Edit',
        submenu: [Object],
        type: 'submenu',
        role: null,
        accelerator: null,
        icon: null,
        sublabel: '',
        enabled: true,
        visible: true,
        checked: false,
        commandId: 12,
        click: [Function],
        menu: [Circular] },
     '22':
      MenuItem {
        label: 'View',
        submenu: [Object],
        type: 'submenu',
        role: null,
        accelerator: null,
        icon: null,
        sublabel: '',
        enabled: true,
        visible: true,
        checked: false,
        commandId: 22,
        click: [Function],
        menu: [Circular] },
     '25':
      MenuItem {
        role: 'window',
        submenu: [Object],
        type: 'submenu',
        accelerator: null,
        icon: null,
        label: 'Window',
        sublabel: '',
        enabled: true,
        visible: true,
        checked: false,
        commandId: 25,
        click: [Function],
        menu: [Circular] },
     '30':
      MenuItem {
        role: 'help',
        submenu: [Object],
        type: 'submenu',
        accelerator: null,
        icon: null,
        label: 'Help',
        sublabel: '',
        enabled: true,
        visible: true,
        checked: false,
        commandId: 30,
        click: [Function],
        menu: [Circular] } },
  groupsMap: {},
  items:
   [ MenuItem {
       label: 'File',
       submenu: [Object],
       type: 'submenu',
       role: null,
       accelerator: null,
       icon: null,
       sublabel: '',
       enabled: true,
       visible: true,
       checked: false,
       commandId: 2,
       click: [Function],
       menu: [Circular] },
     MenuItem {
       label: 'Edit',
       submenu: [Object],
       type: 'submenu',
       role: null,
       accelerator: null,
       icon: null,
       sublabel: '',
       enabled: true,
       visible: true,
       checked: false,
       commandId: 12,
       click: [Function],
       menu: [Circular] },
     MenuItem {
       label: 'View',
       submenu: [Object],
       type: 'submenu',
       role: null,
       accelerator: null,
       icon: null,
       sublabel: '',
       enabled: true,
       visible: true,
       checked: false,
       commandId: 22,
       click: [Function],
       menu: [Circular] },
     MenuItem {
       role: 'window',
       submenu: [Object],
       type: 'submenu',
       accelerator: null,
       icon: null,
       label: 'Window',
       sublabel: '',
       enabled: true,
       visible: true,
       checked: false,
       commandId: 25,
       click: [Function],
       menu: [Circular] },
     MenuItem {
       role: 'help',
       submenu: [Object],
       type: 'submenu',
       accelerator: null,
       icon: null,
       label: 'Help',
       sublabel: '',
       enabled: true,
       visible: true,
       checked: false,
       commandId: 30,
       click: [Function],
       menu: [Circular] } ],
  delegate:
   { isCommandIdChecked: [Function: isCommandIdChecked],
     isCommandIdEnabled: [Function: isCommandIdEnabled],
     isCommandIdVisible: [Function: isCommandIdVisible],
     getAcceleratorForCommandId: [Function: getAcceleratorForCommandId],
     getIconForCommandId: [Function: getIconForCommandId],
     executeCommand: [Function: executeCommand],
     menuWillShow: [Function: menuWillShow] } }
```

which has 'window' and 'help' MenuItems! I really don't understand how I should use the method; the [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menugetapplicationmenu) say it

> Returns Menu | null - The application menu, if set, or null, if not set.

but I must be missing something obvious?

The `console.log(menu.getApplicationMenu())` gives me `TypeError: menu.getApplicationMenu is not a function`

Comment: Don't you want to call [`setApplicationMenu`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu) first?

Comment: @pushkin Is that another method!? I've been using setMenu and I thought that's it

Comment: `console.log(menu.getApplicationMenu()); //error` leads to an error, because `getApplicationMenu` is a static member, not an instance member

Comment: I'll need to do a bit of research, but they're two different methods. [Menu.setApplicationMenu](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu) vs [window.setMenu(...)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows). I guess the latter sets a menu for a specific window. Maybe the former applies the menu to all windows.

Comment: So the one you want to use depends on the behavior you want.

Comment: @pushkin that's it!!!! it all works now! it seems like setApplicationMenu is for the entire application (which is what I want) but setMenu works on individual BrowserWindows? if you post an answer I'll accept it! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Menu.getApplicationMenu()`, but you're never calling [`Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu), which sets the menu for the entire application.

Rather, you're calling `win.setMenu(menu)`,  which sets the menu for a specific window, which does not appear to be what you want.

Comment: in an unpackaged app getApplicationMenu returns the default menu (with items like FIle, Edit, etc.) in a packaged app it returns null, but i'm having trouble finding where this happens in the source code

Comment: that's odd. The code is [here](https://github.com/tabishmahfuz1/electron/blob/c33017c703d23af4b068a9e2f296df9728ca0a28/lib/browser/api/menu.ts#L161)